# ggplot2 with two legends: one horizontally, the other vertically

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with two legends. To fit them well, I want to have the first legend aligned horizontally and the other aligned vertically. I already tried using guides() and legend.direction together with legend.box.

**What I get now**

[image]

**Desired**

[image]

**Reproducable example:**

`> pcaData`

| PC1 | PC2 | Stage | Patient |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -36.25 | -20.15 | Plaque | Pat1 |
| 13.43 | -38.35 | Patch | Pat3 |
| 43.57 | -11.17 | nonlesional | Pat3 |
| -16.50 | 5.4 | Plaque | Pat4 |
| -6.896498 | 7.555632 | nonlesional | Pat4 |
| -10.16 | -13.76 | Patch | Pat5 |

```
PCAplot = ggplot(pcaData, aes(PC1, PC2, color=Patient, shape=Stage)) +
    geom_point(size=4) +
     scale_shape_manual(values=Stage_shape) + theme_bw() + scale_color_manual(values = Patient_Colour) +
    theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title=element_blank(), 
       legend.key.size = unit(1, units = "char"), legend.spacing = unit(-0.5, "line"))
```

Change legend direction

```
PCAplot +theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.box = "horizontal")
```

I also tried playing around with guides() but do not get the desired output.

```
PCAplot +theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.box = "horizontal") +
guides(size=guide_legend(direction='vertical'))
```

Comment: Your data does not contain `Stage_shape` and `Patient_Colour`. Please see your data.

Comment: As your are mapping on `shape` not `size` try `guides(shape=guide_legend(direction='vertical'))`